# How to color specific letter in a string variable (js,angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

As title says i want to color a specific letter in a string variable.

I got my string in a table as angularjs variable like this:

```
<td>{{variable}}<td>
```

In javascript file where i am passing a variable for angular i got string from server side which looks something like this: WWLWL

```
var exampleString= 'WWLWL';
$scope.variable = exampleString;
```

And i want to color W as a green and L as a red and show it in html table by using anugaljs to display variable

Is there any way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting the string to array of chars, like this:

Template:

```
<td>
    <span ng-repeat="char in chars track by $index" class="char-{{char}}"}>{{char}}</span>
<td>
```

Controller:

```
var exampleString = 'WWLWL';
var chars = exampleString.split('');
$scope.chars = chars;
```

CSS:

```
.char-W { color: green; }
.char-L { color: red; }
```

Comment: should `track by $index` due to duplicates

Comment: ng-repeat is a overkill, you don't want to create new scope fro 1st and last later

Comment: well you might be right but IMHO it looks more readable than your solution

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, appreciate your help, that worked for me.